# Slick-Slider next and previous button not activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I have a custom slick slider gallery that gets activated when you click on the gallery image. But the previous and next arrows do not work. When you select them the gallery reverts back to the original image. I have tried to use 
`z-index: 100;` but it doesn't seem to work. I am new to JavaScript so I think it has to do with the fact that the whole div is clickable.

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/protonus/jje5a1dr/4/) which seems to have the arrows, but not the code I inserted below.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".div2").hide();

  $(".div1").on("click", function() {
    $(".div2").hide();
    $(".div1").show();

    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().show();

  });

  $(".div2").on("click", function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev().show();
  });
});
$('.carousel-one').slick({
  arrows: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000
});
```

```css
.slick-next {
  right: 20px;
  /* background-color: black; */
  z-index: 100;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: 20px;
  /* background-color: black; */
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200" alt="Image three"></div>
<div class="div2">
  <div class="carousel-one">
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image three"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image one"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image two"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/200" alt="Image four"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image five"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="Image seven"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image six"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200" alt="Image three"></div>
<div class="div2">
  <div class="carousel-one">
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image three"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image one"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image two"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/200" alt="Image four"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image five"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="Image seven"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image six"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200" alt="Image three"></div>
<div class="div2">
  <div class="carousel-one">
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image three"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image one"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image two"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/200" alt="Image four"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image five"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="Image seven"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image six"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at this for some guidance - https://codepen.io/aphextwix/pen/XRRjBb. It appears that `slick` hasn't been initialised in your example, which would explain why you aren't seeing the arrows.

Comment: The problem is event bubbling. When clicking on the button, the event bubbles up to parent `div2` and that's what your click handler will detect.

Comment: @yezzz is there a way to get the click handler to ignore the `div2` where the arrows appear? aphextwix, it works on jsfiddle and on my website when I run it, not sure why it doesn't initialise in the code snippet above.

Comment: Hang on I'll create an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button click event bubbles up, and `div2` click handler catches it. One way to deal with it is to exit the function if the clicked element is a button.

Here's a way to do it in javascript. I've also added some console.log for you to check out in your console and play around with. Go try do it in jquery, use class selector, etc.

```
  $(".div2").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("div2 click event:", event); // js event obj
    console.log("div2 click event:", e); // jQuery event object
    if (event.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") return; // exit if button
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev().show();
  });
```

Working code: http://jsfiddle.net/jje5a1dr/5/

Comment: Cheers,  just expand the objects in your log, the event target is the element your clicked...